# What library to use when generating Spotify playlists

Tags: .net, spotify

I need to generate real Spotify playlists (not a text string that you can drop on Spotify) belonging to a real Spotify-user (me). My tools are .NET 4.0 and Javascript.

It is a web app i'm creating not a Spotify-app living in Spotify.

What is the best/easiest library to use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where will your app live?

If you're building an app inside Spotify, use this library: http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/preview/reference/

If you're building a web app outside Spotify, you can try libspotify: https://github.com/jonasl/libspotify-sharp

Be warned, the last link I posted it not up to date.

If you're looking for a web API for building playlists, it's not available now, but it's something we've been thinking about creating.

Comment: Thanks! Updated my question. I was afraid that that was the best library. If i don't get any better suggestions i'll try that out and mark your answer as accepted.