# Setting up Spotify-API-server

Tags: c, spotify

I'm trying to generate spotify playlists (not text-based) and found this on Github: https://github.com/liesen/spotify-api-server

I have no experience in C programming so i don't really know where to start. Are there any relevant tutorials/articles on setting up a c-server similar to the one i'm trying to set up? on a pretty basic level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a sneaking suspicion that building and using this C program isn't actually what you want (http://developer.spotify.com/en/spotify-apps-api/overview/ might be easier for you to get started with), but I'm going to help you anyway.

Most C projects have a README file that tells you how to build them. In this case, it says:

1. Make sure you have the required libraries

   - [libspotify](http://developer.spotify.com/en/libspotify/) > 9
   - subversion (`libsvn-dev`) and its dependency, `libapr`
   - [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) >= 2.0
   - [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) >= 2.0
2. Update `account.c` with your credentials. A *Spotify premium account is necessary*.
3. Copy `appkey.c` into the directory and run `make`.

There are a few extra things that the README doesn't say, that an experienced developer will be able to guess at:

1. libsvn-dev and libapr are the names of Ubuntu packages (I think), so it is probably expecting your development machine to be running Ubuntu. You should probably install build-essentials as well (on a new machine, I would usually run `apt-get install ${*-dev-packagages}` and then `apt-get build-dep ${*-dev-packages}`. `build-dep` might download some packages that you don't need, but bandwidth is cheap, and debugging missing packages is a pain in the ass.
2. when it says [libspotify](http://developer.spotify.com/en/libspotify/) > 9 it normally means "greater than 9 but less than 10" (if the first number in a C-library version number changes, it normally means "BEWARE: we broke things."). If you get build errors about wrong number of arguments to functions, this is probably why.
3. It says "run `make`" so there will be a file called `Makefile` somewhere. You need to `cd` into the directory that contains `Makefile` before typing `make`
4. `make` will probably produce an executable file somewhere. I usually find these by running `ls` and looking for items highlighted in green. If I can't find anything that way, I will read Makefile and note that "all" depends on "server" so I would look for an executable called "server".

You are jumping in at the deep end here (building someone else's experimental package as your first C program). If you get errors that you don't understand, it's not because you're stupid: it's because C is a brutal and archaic language, and it wasn't designed as a teaching language like Python was, or a beginner-friendly language like Javascript. Once you get used to it, you start to see steamtrain-like beauty of the language; the pain subsides to a dull ache, but it never truly goes away.

Comment: Great summary. I see your point, but personally I would be mad if providing version 10 to satisfy a requirement of > 9 didn't work.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that this is the best/easiest way to do it but i have asked this question too here on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989434/what-library-to-use-when-generating-spotify-playlists

Comment: I have talked myself out of this project with the arguments that this is way over my head. But your answer is so pedagogical i think i'm going to try it out anyway (outside work). Thanks!